# How are we going to hit next url using python and selenium IDE

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying  to hit next url using python and selenium IDE.

It is showing only first link then error for next URL.I do not know what I am missing here. Can anyone help me out?

**Here is my code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#base Url
baseurl="http://www.happytrips.com/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
link_name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div[3]/div/nav/div/ul/li/a")

for tab1 in link_name: 
    driver.implicitly_wait(3) 
    tab1_destination=tab1.get_attribute('href')
    print tab1_destination  
    driver.get(tab1_destination)
```

**Output**

```
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "happytest1.py", line 13, in <module>
    tab1_destination=tab1.get_attribute('href')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 402, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8953)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpH_Pmgs/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8546)
    at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///tmp/tmpH_Pmgs/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11746)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpH_Pmgs/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpH_Pmgs/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:603)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a get of another page, all existing elements become invalid. You need to get all of the URLs before switching to a new page.

So, add another loop. The first loop iterates over the elements to save each URL, and the second loop iterates over the list of URLs rather than over the list of elements.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, I have stored all links in an array then hit one by one.now it is working.